# Contact Status is missing trying to use them in a Workflow

Tags: workflow, leads, contact

I am using the NGO version of Salesforce to track candidate application. I would like to update the Lead status when a contact is created and also when Contact status changes. Is it possible to do this through a Workflow?

I tried to create a workflow in Lead that will copy the Contact Status but I am unable to find the Contact Status field.

Comment: You're asking a fairly broad question that's difficult to answer.  You're best bet is to **Google "workflow examples salesforce"** and look for a good tutorial.  If you have a specific example you are trying to get to work, then you're at the right place.  Please add specific details - the  more the better!  (It's easy to add images (screen shots) to your question too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to update the Lead status when a contact is created and also when Contact status changes. Is it possible to do this through a Workflow?

In short, no.  A workflow can only apply Field Updates to the record that kicked off the workflow, in your case the Contact record.  It cannot modifiy the Lead for you.  You would need an Apex Trigger on the Contact object to seek out the relevant Lead(s) and update them.